# How to make stored image folder should be accessible only through php code

Tags: php, image, directory, store

I'm Using mysql database and my coding php
i want to secure uploaded images files folder only accessible through my code. i dont know how to explain this. i want like password protected folder or encrypted files like this.

on my page if did img src='' should be accessible.

but when user's browser when tried to access image stored folder should not accessible.

Comment: Put files in a folder above the DocumentRoot so they cannot be servered directly from apache

Comment: is it possible to upload user when upload through my form

Comment: Yes, PHP can access folder there but not a simple http request

Comment: // Location
$location = "images/".$new_profle_pic;
// file extension
$file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_extension = strtolower($file_extension); like this code possible to access is it???

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using apache., ou could try using .htaccess like (on upload folder):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

No one but your server will be able to get data from that directory through the webserver (apache).